# Re-Authentication in Twitter Digits

Tags: java, android, twitter-digits

I recently just started using [Twitter Digits](https://get.digits.com/).

I'm having problems, the fact is that when I first logged in (sms came in with the code, went through the `Authentication`, and received a message in `Toast` "Authentication successful for").

But when the second time I try to open the page to fill the number, I press the button and I get again a message about successful `authentication`.

Code in onCreate method:

```
DigitsAuthButton digitsButton = (DigitsAuthButton) findViewById(R.id.auth_button);
        digitsButton.setCallback(new AuthCallback() {
            @Override
            public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
                // TODO: associate the session userID with your user model
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication successful for "
                        + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
                Log.d("Digits", "Sign in with Digits failure", exception);
            }
        });
```

Question: How do I clear a session or re-authorize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call **Digits.logout()**

```
/**
 * Log user out of this device - this clears the active Digits session, if one exists
 * Note: You will no longer get updates to the user's profile information
 * (email, phone number, etc) without an active Digits session.
 */
public static void logout(){
    getInstance().sessionManager.clearActiveSession();
}
```

before calling

```
Digits.authenticate();
```